# Вывести сообщение, что каждый элемент списка содержит вхождение регулярного выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

### 1. Кратко

См. заголовок.

---

### 2. Минимальный пример

Имеется список.

```python
sashalist = ['Sasha1', 'Sasha14', 'Sasha4147']
```

Необходимо проверить, что каждый элемент списка содержит `$вхождение`, и если действительно содержит, вывести сообщение.

Положим, `$вхождение` — цифра `1`. Работающий пример:

- [**Демо на Ideone**](https://ideone.com/i0Fivd)

```python
sashalist = ['Sasha1', 'Sasha14', 'Sasha4147']

if all('1' in item for item in sashalist):
    print('Все элементы списка содержат «1»!')
```

- Вывод:

```python
Все элементы списка содержат «1»!
```

Если же `$вхождение` — это регулярное выражение, (например, `\d`), то не найду, что я должен сделать.

---

### 3. Попытки справиться с проблемой самостоятельно

#### 3.1. Аналогия

- [**Демо на Ideone**](https://ideone.com/C3HREC)

```python
import re


sashalist = ['Sasha1', 'Sasha14', 'Sasha4147']
sasharegex = r'\d'

if all(re.search(sasharegex, sashalist) in item for item in sashalist):
    print('Все элементы списка содержат цифру!')
```

- Получаю traceback:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 7, in <genexpr>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 173, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

#### 3.2. Цикл

- [**Демо на Ideone**](https://ideone.com/eUiOJ2)

```python
import re


sashalist = ['Sasha1', 'Sasha14', 'Sasha4147']
sasharegex = r'\d'

for item in sashalist:
    sasharegexsearch = re.search(sasharegex, item)
    if sasharegexsearch:
        print("Все пункты списка содержат цифру!")
```

- Сообщение выводится после проверки каждого элемента:

```python
Все пункты списка содержат цифру!
Все пункты списка содержат цифру!
Все пункты списка содержат цифру!
```

А нужно, чтобы вывелось одно сообщение после успешной проверки всего списка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://ideone.com/msQnop

```
import re


sashalist = ['Sasha1', 'Sasha14', 'Sasha4147']
sasharegex = r'Sas'

if all(re.search(sasharegex, item) for item in sashalist):
    print('All elements have sasharegex !')
```